# Error after EE2.9 update. Conditional fix required

Tags: conditionals

The below code no longer works with EE2.9 Have tried determining how to change it but cannot work it out. I just need to specify that if ANY of the fields exist, display the content (div/header/row/info).

Any help is appreciated!

```
{if jumper_colour|sash_colour|tie_colour|saddle_colour|rally_colour}
<div id="container">
<h4>CLUB COLOURS</h4>

  {if jumper_colour}<div id="row">
    <div id="ff"><h5>Jumper:</h5></div>
    <div id="ee"><p>{jumper_colour}</p></div>
  </div>{/if}
  {if sash_colour}<div id="row">
    <div id="ff"><h5>Sash:</h5></div>
    <div id="ee"><p>{sash_colour}</p></div>
  </div>{/if}
  {if tie_colour}<div id="row">
    <div id="ff"><h5>Tie:</h5></div>
    <div id="ee"><p>{tie_colour}</p></div>
  </div>{/if}
  {if saddle_colour}<div id="row">
    <div id="ff"><h5>Saddle Cloth:</h5></div>
    <div id="ee"><p>{saddle_colour}</p></div>
  <div>{/if}
  {if rally_colour}<div id="row">
    <div id="ff"><h5>Rally Uniform:</h5></div>
    <div id="ee"><p>{rally_colour}</p></div>
  </div>{/if}

</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok finally worked out that all i needed to do was add a double pipe character between fields.

```
{if jumper_colour || sash_colour || tie_colour || saddle_colour || rally_colour}
```